# Dedicated dump file - why set the size twice?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, debugging, pagefile

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/how-to-determine-the-appropriate-page-file-size-for-64-bit-versions-of-windows#dedicated-dump-files):

> Computers that are running Microsoft Windows or Microsoft Windows
> Server usually must have a page file to support a system crash dump.
> System administrators can now create a dedicated dump file instead.
>
> A dedicated dump file is a page file that isn't used for paging.
> Instead, it is "dedicated" to back a system crash dump file ... use a
> dedicated dump file if you want a system crash dump but you don't want
> a page file.

Though the above file links to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/memory-dump-file-options) saying:

> To learn how to create it, see Overview of memory dump file options
> for Windows.

It seems like the instructions are really on the Microsoft page titled [Configure memory dump files for Server Core installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-memory-dump):

In [step 2, section 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-memory-dump#step-2-configure-the-destination-path-for-a-memory-dump) we set the **DumpFileSize**.

But then in [step 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-memory-dump#step-7-set-the-memory-dumps-page-file-size), we set the dump's **page file** size.

It would seem that the first one is the size of the result file itself, but that is set in [step 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-memory-dump#step-3-set-the-type-of-memory-dump), because there we set the **type** of dump, which automatically affects the size.

I'm assuming it's not really setting the size twice, but what *is* it doing? In fact, it would seem that **one** place would be enough for a dedicated dump file.